# Setup a mysql replication, but new data are not updated

Tags: mysql, replication

I have setup a MySQL replication for an existing database server. The setup seems fine, but the database never update on slave server after I start the replication. Both servers are using CentOS 5.7 64-bit. They have enough disk space.

### From MySQL Master server

mysql> show variables like 'server_id';
| server_id     | 1     |

mysql> show processlist;
| 391673 | repl| mysqlslave.mydomain.com:47453 | NULL | Binlog Dump | 1453 | Has sent all binlog to slave; waiting for binlog to be updated | NULL

mysql> show slave hosts;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show master status;
| mysql-bin.000008 |98 | db1, db2 |

#### From MySQL Slave server

mysql> show variables like 'server_id';
server_id     | 2

mysql> show slave status \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                Master_Host: 192.168.1.2
                Master_User: repl
                Master_Port: 3306
              Connect_Retry: 60
            Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000008
        Read_Master_Log_Pos: 98
             Relay_Log_File: slave-relay-bin.000004
              Relay_Log_Pos: 235
      Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000008
           Slave_IO_Running: Yes
          Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
            Replicate_Do_DB: db1; db2

## MySQL log

In slave server, the message log shows this

> 111031 10:53:16 [Note] Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'mysql-bin.000008', position 98
>   111031 10:53:16 [Note] Error reading relay log event: slave SQL thread was killed
>   111031 10:53:16 [Note] Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'mysql-bin.000008' at position 98, relay log './slave-relay-bin.000001' position: 4
>   111031 10:53:16 [Note] Slave I/O thread: connected to master 'repl@192.168.1.2:3306',  replication started in log 'mysql-bin.000008' at position 98

## Update

If I create a new database on master server, it will be replicated to the slave server, but the existing databases are not updated.

## Last Update

Instead of dump all the databases and setup replication in one time, I do it one by one and it is working fine now.

Comment: Please run this command on both slave and master, and post the output in your question: `show databases`

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to post customer's db names here. It contains their userID and domainname. The master server has 44 rows, the slave server has 41 rows. When I dump the databases from master server, i skipped 3 corrupted databases. I thought it should be ok to replicate the other databases. Am I wrong?

Comment: I see another problem. Don't worry about showing DB names. I supplied an answer.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running on Master and Slave ?

Comment: Both are 5.0.77

Answer (score 3):

I think I see the problem

You have the following in your question:

```
Replicate_Do_DB: db1; db2
```

That is not supposed to be a semicolon-separated list. It is supposed to be a comma-separated list.

My guess is your have this in your slave's /etc/my.cnf

```
replicate-do-db=db1; db2
```

The correct way to set this up is

```
replicate-do-db=db1
replicate-do-db=db2
```

Please adjust this in the slave's /etc/my.cnf and restart mysql on the slave

Give it a Try !!!

#### **UPDATE 2011-10-31 15:20 EDT**

You may want to clear out the relay log by doing this

```
STOP SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO master_log_file='mysql-bin.000008',master_log_pos-98;
START SLAVE;
```

then run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` and make sure replication is running by making sure you see this

```
Slave_IO_Running: Yes
Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
```

just as you posted in your question

Comment: Thanks. This is a problem. I've fixed it and the problem still exists.

Comment: One question: if i have multiple dbs waiting to be replicated, but in my.cnf, i only set one for testing, will that work?

Comment: Answer to this question is yes. Each time you change the replicate-do-db list, please restart mysql.

Comment: 10 years later Rolando still saving my @$$! <3